# Automatic pairing using 32-feet bluetooth API's for Win CE 7 OS

Tags: bluetooth, windows-ce

I am intending to connect a device 1 (in master mode, Bluetooth Ver 2.1) to a device 2 (in slave mode with Win CE 7 OS, Microsoft Bluetooth Ver 2.1).

Here I need the connection to happen without any user interaction and automatically accept the pairing on device 2 running WIN CE 7 OS.

On similar device 2 if running Windows 7 OS, this can be achieved by handling in **BluetoothWin32Authentication** callback function by **"e.Confirm"** of 32feet InTheHand.Net.Personal.dll API.

Could someone help in navigating to correct set of API's (if exists) to enable similar automatic pair accept behavior for **Win CE 7 OS**.

Will be very grateful for the guidance.

Thank you.